# Add where clause, LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, where-clause

I have:

```
 var x = from os in dbLinq.vmesne_ures
         where ((os._projekt_id).Equals(_cb_projekt_id))
         orderby os.projekt_name
         group new { vm_oseba_id = os._oseba_id } by os._oseba_id into uniqueIds
         select uniqueIds.FirstOrDefault();
```

It returns unique ids. Is it possible to add `where` clause to `x`? Something like

```
 var y = x ... where os._oseba_id < 100
```

I know i can do where `((os._projekt_id).Equals(_cb_projekt_id) && where os._oseba_id < 100)` or similar. I'm looking for exactly this solution if i can add to `x` another `where`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can add another where clause

```
var x = from os in dbLinq.vmesne_ures
         where ((os._projekt_id).Equals(_cb_projekt_id))
         where os._oseba_id < 100
         orderby os.projekt_name
         group new { vm_oseba_id = os._oseba_id } by os._oseba_id into uniqueIds
         select uniqueIds.FirstOrDefault();
```

the only difference between two wheres and && operator is that two delegates are created, but the algorithm is still O(n)

Comment: Can i add directly to x? Something like `x.where` ... If you know what i'm tryin to do

Comment: @Traktor you have build the whole query var y = from os in x where .... Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Something like `var y = From i in x where i._oseba_id < 100` ?

Comment: yes. Yet another LINQ query (mind you are creating anonymous type and you want to filter vm_oseba_id now and select the object). That's a bad idea, though.

Comment: Yes it is better. less code less possible bugs and you introduce another variable. Lucky, LINQ has delayed execution and will not filter the collection twice.